# Update ViewModel A's property from ViewModel B in UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, properties

MainPage displays a list and a button. The source of the ListView is Addresses (databinding). When the user clicks the button, AddAddressPage opens. Both have their own ViewModel. In AddAddressPage the user can fill out a formular and click a button to add the new address to the list. Everything works except the update. After the address is added nothing happens and I have to restart the app to see the new address (I tried an ObservableCollection as well). I've used breaking points and noticed that the Getter doesn't get called but the Setter twice.

MainPageViewModel:

```
private List<Address> addresses;

public List<Address> Addresses
{
    get
    {
        return this.addresses;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(ref this.addresses, value);
    }
}
```

SetValue:

```
public void SetValue<T>(ref T Backingfield, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Backingfield, value))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Backingfield = value;

        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

AddAddressViewModel:

```
// Code to insert new address into SQLite database here...

MainPageViewModel mpvm = new MainPageViewModel();
mpvm.Addresses = SQLite.Select(); // Select returns the database as List
```

Comment: Does the second window share the same VM with View A or is it a separate one? I think you need to be a bit more clear about that in your title and the body of the question.

Comment: It is a separate one.

Comment: So if I am getting it right you are updating the database from ViewModel B and you want the change to be picked up from ViewModel A. ViewModel A does not poll the DB and the DB does not fire events whenever it is updated. What I would do in this situation is use some sort of messenger for VM to VM communication which is part of the MVVM architecture. I don't know which framework you are using if you are using one, but take for example the [MVVMLight messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/mvvm-the-mvvm-light-messenger-in-depth)

Comment: In your AddAddressViewModel, when you tried to assign the value from SQLite.Select() method to Addresses in MainPageViewModel, I noticed you created a new MainPageViewModel instance instead of the existed MainPageViewModel from MainPage. If you assign the lists from database to the viewmodel in your MainPage, will the same issue occur?

Comment: No, the error only occurs when I try to assign the value from another ViewModel.

Comment: When I tested, I can update the data well. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, although you assign the updated value in AddAddressViewModel, since the mpvm you created is not bound with the ListView in MainPage, it changes but doesn't affect the ListView. So you can subscribe the **Closed** event of your new Window, when you close your AddAddressPage, the event will be triggered. Then you can return to your mainview and assign the new data to its Addresses property. For example:

MainPageViewModel.cs:

```
private async void ToAddAddress()
{
    CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    var newViewId = 0;

    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(AddAddressPage), this.addresses);
        Window.Current.Content = frame;

        // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
        Window.Current.Activate();
        Window.Current.Closed += Current_Closed;
        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });

    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);            
}

private async void Current_Closed(object sender, CoreWindowEventArgs e)
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        this.Addresses = SQLite.Select();
    });
}
```